# Best practice to set up JavaScript event handlers for partial views

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a partial view that is loaded via JQuery ajax. It enumerates through properties in the Model and renders HTML elements which need JavaScript events bound.

Here is some simplified razor code I have now

```
foreach(MyObject item Model.MyObjectList)
{

   string containerId = "Container" + item.Id;
   string onMouseOut = "DoSomething('"+containerId+"',@Model.Id)";
   <div id="@containerId" onmouseout="@onMouseOut">
     //Other code here
  </div>
}
```

This works OK however it is often said to be better to bind events in JQuery, if I did this you could also utilise JQuery events such as "onmouseleave".

So another method I could do is place a script block inside each enumeration which sets up the events like so

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $('#@containerId').mouseout(function(){
   DoSomething('@containerId',@Model.Id)
  });
</script>
```

However this results in lots of script block being rendered.

Is there another better solution for setting up events in partial views?

Comment: Consider using jQuery delegates. Instead of adding an event handler for each `containerId` set a class on those "container `div`s" and bind them using `on`. That way you'll always need only one handler, regardless of how many containers you load and the code could reside on your main page.

Comment: You should only ever render one script block. Use a class name rather than an `id` attribute, and then `$('.container').mouseout(function() { ...` If you need to store and retrieve a model value (e.g. the `ID`), store using `data-` attributes

Answer (score 0):

Use the .on method to bind events to things that will not always be inside the DOM.

```
$('#foo').on('click', function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

You then remove the need to insert script tags in your partials. There was a method similar to this that was .live() but has since been deprecated in v1.7 and removed since v1.9.

[jQuery API : .on();](http://api.jquery.com/on/)